# Three-column CSS layout - fixed/max./variable width

Tags: css, layout, css-float, variable-width

I'm having trouble getting the following three-column layout to work:

```
    A              B              C
+-------+-------------------+------------+
|       |                   |            |
| Fixed | Use unused space  |  Resizable |
|       |                   |            |
+-------+-------------------+------------+
```

Where:

- **A** is fixed width.
- **B** uses any available space in the container not used by the columns A and C.
- **C** contains content which may change width and need to "push" B to a
  different width.

Here is my best attempt at creating this:
http://jsfiddle.net/x3ESz/

All the other topics I have looked at suggest having all three as floating with B using margins to prevent wrapping, but this doesn't allow for C to resize B based on C's content (as a value must be given for B's right margin).

I also really want to avoid resorting to JS to achieve this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This can easily be solved by [adding `overflow: hidden`](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats) to `#div_middle` and removing the margins:

```
#div_middle {
    overflow: hidden;
    border:1px solid #0F0;
}
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/x3ESz/1/

This works in all modern browsers and IE7+.

Comment: A much simpler solution than I would've expected. Works perfectly. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it without changing your layout if you use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div_right').click(function() {
        $(this).append('--');
        $('#div_middle').css("margin-right", $('#div_right').width() + 2 +"px");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does even work with both variable width sidebars :

http://jsfiddle.net/QG2EU/

```
#div_left{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #F00;
}
#div_middle {
    overflow: hidden;
    border:1px solid #0F0;
}
#div_right {
    float:right;
    border:1px solid #00F;
}
```